# Java-Applet will not release focus in Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, applet, focus

I have an Java Applet with some TextFields. When I Click in any TextField, it gets the focus, I see the caret and I can write my text. OK.

But now I ckick in the address field of the Browser, I get a second caret and any KeyEvent is dispachted by the Applet, so I can't type in a new URL in the Browser. This url is written to my Applet textfield.

It works with chrome. But not with firefox.

**update**

It works in firefox 9, too. But not in firefox 10.

Comment: *"It works in firefox 9, too. But not in firefox 10."* If that is using the same JRE version, I'd say the problem is FireFox (lacking further evidence otherwise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the final answer on this one, but I can confirm that I am having the same problem, and reinstalling FF9 fixes the issue. I have tried various focus settings of the applet components to see if they were related but nothing seems to work around this problem except:

1. Hit Windows-Tab. That seems to unlock it.
2. I have a button in my applet that brings up a file chooser. Clicking that and cancelling unlocks things. The moment I click in an area of the applet again I can no longer type in the location or search bar.

**Update**

Got a response in the FF forums on this one:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718939

See comment #40. The patch build referenced there fixed the problem for me. They say it should be officially released soon.